# Why is the 16th Karmapa visualized rather than the 17th Karmapa in Karma Kagyu?

Tags: tibetan-buddhism

From what I have seen observing Kagyu ceremonies, the 17th Karmapa (either of them, actually) is treated with great awe, respect and reverence. However in their daily rituals, Kagyu buddhists usually visualize the late 16th Karmapa. I assume this is the result of a certain prescription within Karma Kagyu but I was unable to find explanations of this on the Internet.

So, why do Kagyu followers visualize the late instead of the current holders of the Karmapa office? Does this have to do with the status of the late living Buddha as opposed to the living living Buddha?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not true that it is done by the prescription of the Kagyu. I asked one of the senior students at the Dagpo Kagyu Ling center near me, who is very close to the head of that center, so he is in a position to know the answer. He told me that people can choose who they visualize during their practice, either the 17th Karmapa, Thaye Dorje, or the 16th Karmapa, Rangdrung Rigpe Dorje. What is true, is that there exists a special Guru Yoga practice text for the 16th Karmapa and not yet a formal Guru Yoga practice text for the 17th Karmapa.

Answer (score -2):

> So, why do Kagyu followers visualize the late instead of the current holders of the Karmapa office? Does this have to do with the status of the late living Buddha as opposed to the living living Buddha?

Maybe because there's yet any conclusive resolution to the [Karmapa controversy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karmapa_controversy)? But anyway, just to clarify, you probably meant living [Tulkus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tulku), not living Buddhas, for there can't be multiple Buddhas existing in the same world system. After Gotama Buddha's passing, and after a long period, the next Buddha will be Metteyya, who's currently carrying out His bodhisattvic duties up there in the Tusita heaven. All others will be just teachers with various degrees of attainments from now until that time.

> “He understands: ‘It is impossible, it cannot happen that two Accomplished Ones, Fully Enlightened Ones, could arise contemporaneously in one world-system—there is no such possibility.’1089 And he understands: ‘It is possible that one Accomplished One, a Fully Enlightened One, might arise in one world-system—there is such a possibility.’ He understands: ‘It is impossible, it cannot happen that two Wheel-turning Monarchs could arise contemporaneously in one world-system…It is possible that one Wheel-turning Monarch might arise in one worldsystem—there is such a possibility.’ ~~ [MN 115](https://suttacentral.net/mn115/en/sujato) ~~

Comment: I think that the definition of a 'Buddha' varies according to each tradition. For traditions that considerate EBTs as their primary source, you definition is valid.

Comment: @BrianDíazFlores, MN 115 is not an EBT, but a universal text common to all Buddhist traditions. See this link for a long list of its equivalents from various sources: https://suttacentral.net/mn115/

Comment: EBT means Early Buddhist Text, which MN definitely is. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Buddhist_texts

Comment: @AndreiVolkov, have u looked at its Chinese, Taisho, and Tibetan equivalents on the link I gave? No, MN 115 is not solely EBT. By the way, the Karmapa's never claimed himself to be a living Buddha. Feel free to provide proof and/or backup evidence saying the opposite.

Comment: I'm just saying "early buddhist text" means "a Buddhist text written relatively early". Can't argue with that, can you? Or do you think Majjhima Nikaya is not a buddhist text or that it was not written early?

Comment: And I'm just saying the Karmapas are no living Buddhas. Can't argue with that, can you? Or do you think there're a bunch of living Buddhas right here in our wold system?

Comment: Hi Santa! I was just trying to say that if a sect or tradition doesn't care about EBTs, they might use another definition for the word "Buddha". For instance, I've read some mahayana fellows who don't think that texts widely considered EBTs to be actually early nor authentic. And so, they use their own definition of 'Buddha'; one that might see Nagarjuna as a second Buddha, even within the current world-system. Kind regards!

Comment: @BrianDíazFlores, as mentioned, MN 115 has its parallels in so many texts in all traditions. So it'd be mistaken to say that this is solely an EBT thingy. Anyway, of course people are entitled to their own opinions and there's nothing we can do about that. We can only cite the sources and leave it up to them to decide what to believe.

Comment: @santa100 I'm not if we agree on this, but when I speak about EBTs, I'm not only referring to texts of the Pali Canon, but all those other texts and fragments that are parallel (in content and/or time of writing) to those of the Pali Canon. And as long as a tradition sees EBTs as a primary source of authority, then they might agree on your definition of "a Buddha". But not every tradition (AFAIK) holds EBTs in the same hierarchical position. Kind regards!

Comment: @BrianDíazFlores, ok, even given that position, my point still holds: that none of the Karmapa's have outright proclaimed that they are living Buddhas, nor any other masters in any other traditions. Therefore, it wouldn't make any sense at all to elevate some master to the level of a Buddha while s/he's never made that claim themselves!

Comment: @santa100 from my complete ignorance about the Tibetan traditions, I agree. Just to be clear, I was just offering my opinion about your statement: "there can't be multiple Buddhas existing in the same world system". Kind regards!

Comment: @BrianDíazFlores, no problem. Also just to be clear, "there can't be multiple Buddhas existing in the same world system" is not my statement. it's a statement proclaimed not only in the Pali system, but also in the Chinese, Taisho, AND the Tibetan system itself, as cited in the provided link previously.

Comment: The old unanswered question is: since not a single master in all traditions of the modern time claim themselves to be living Buddhas, isn't it a gross ignorance on the part of the followers to elevate their status to be the same as the Buddha??

Comment: Thank you for deepening my understanding. I used the term "living Buddha" since it was in a documentary I watched. Now I realize this is mostly a term the Chinese use in the context of Tibetan Buddhism. I would like to avoid arguing over terminology here since it is inconsequential in context of the asked question itself.

Comment: As to the question itself, I feel no answer was provided. According to my understanding, the Karmapa controversy leads people to believe in one of the Karmapas or both of them being authentic and it does not lead people to believe in the 16th Karmapa being the last authentic Karmapa and neither of the 17th Karmapas being authentic. Besides, it seems to me the Karmapa controversy was more or less resolved recently (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karmapa_controversy#Recent_developments). Therefore the Karmapa controversy is likely inconsequential as well.